# Extracting specific text from cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

how to extract id of PC which respondend to ping from cell of excel...

Comment: You should give some more information on what you are looking for. An example of desired output of the solution perhaps. For example, it is not clear whether one knows in which cell to search for the PC ID beforehand or not; and it is also not clear if there are only 1 or many IDs to be found; you could also specify whether the input always follows the format as shown in your screenshot ...

Answer (score 0):

```
=MID(A1;FIND("PC";A1)+2;8)
```

Output: 00001521